# Make SVN repository public

Tags: svn

I have a local SVN repository. I'd like to make it public, so other people can download it by svn checkout command. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Where do you want it to share ?  On local network or PUBLIC Internet ?

Comment: I meant more a local network. I'll have to do everything by hand in this case. I tried with creating and moving a stub, but I got stuck at 'switch relocate' part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are tons of different sites where you can do that. I think the decision  about the site should be more based in the complemental options like issues management, mailing lists, ....

http://code.google.com

http://sourceforge.net

http://www.berlios.de/

.....

Answer (score 1):

SVN is most often used with http server like Apache. On windows please check VisualSVN server, it is very easy to use: http://www.visualsvn.com/

Answer (score -1):

Google Code is a good place to start.  You can create a project and use Subversion as the source control, and then move your files over.

http://code.google.com